# Горизонтальное выравнивание блоков

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать горизонтальное выравнивание статей в блоге, как высчитать равную ширину с помощью функции `calc()`, задать отступ блокам по 10px?

Но так, чтобы блоки сильно не сжимались, задать им что-то типа фиксированной ширины.

Вот код:

```css
.articles {
    min-height: 500px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #ccc;
}

.articles__list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.articles__item {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="articles">
            <ul class="articles__list">
                <li class="articles__item">
                    <article></article>
                </li>
                <li class="articles__item">
                    <article></article>
                </li>
                <li class="articles__item">
                    <article></article>
                </li>
                <li class="articles__item">
                    <article></article>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

Comment: flexbox вам бы помог намного лучше. Его возможности очень много

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос чисто про `calc`, то вот вам решение:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.articles {
  min-height: 500px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
}

.articles__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

.articles__item {
  background: red;
  width: calc(200px - 10px);
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="articles">
  <ul class="articles__list">
    <li class="articles__item">
      <article></article>
    </li>
    <li class="articles__item">
      <article></article>
    </li>
    <li class="articles__item">
      <article></article>
    </li>
    <li class="articles__item">
      <article></article>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Впрочем, я не совсем понимаю, что именно вы хотите сделать. Если задача в том, чтоб определенное количество блоков вписывалось в ширину - это одно, если речь про фиксированный размер блоков, то не очень понятно, зачем сам `calc`. Зачем высчитывать равную ширину, если можно использовать проценты. Если вопрос в отступах, то, можно использовать `padding` у пунктов списка.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.articles {
  background: #ccc;
}

.articles__list {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

.articles__item {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="articles">
  <ul class="articles__list">
    <li class="articles__item">
      <article></article>
    </li>
    <li class="articles__item">
      <article></article>
    </li>
    <li class="articles__item">
      <article></article>
    </li>
    <li class="articles__item">
      <article></article>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Вы правы. Мне наверное нужно скорей всего, чтоб определенное количество вписывалось в ширину контейнера, но только с отступами друг от друга. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Добавил еще пример